# Why does shell command output sometimes get inserted into an existing buffer?

Tags: shell-command

If I do a <kbd>M-!</kbd> to run a shell command, usually any output will appear in a new, temporary buffer. But sometimes, seemingly at random, the output will instead be inserted directly into the active buffer. If this happens and I run the same command over again, it normally works as expected the second time.

Is this just me? Why might this be happening, and how do I prevent it?

Comment: That's what happens if you hit `C-u`, or `C-` or `M-` with a digit or minus sign, before `M-!`. Might that be what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give `M-!` a prefix argument, any prefix argument, it will insert the output at the point.

`C-h c <key>` will tell you exactly which function is being run when you press a key. In this case, it's `shell-command`. You can read the documentation by typing `C-h f shell-command RET`:

> Execute string COMMAND in inferior shell; display output, if any.
>   With prefix argument, insert the COMMAND's output at point.

You can also use `C-h k` to combine the above two help commands. That is, `C-h k M-!` will open the help window for the command that `M-!` runs, whatever it may be.

Comment: Ah... well then I guess I must be accidentally touching some additional key sometimes, which is interpreted as an argument. I'll `view-lossage` next time it happens to confirm.

Comment: @BrianZ, good idea. If the issue persists, there are some variables (`prefix-arg`, `current-prefix-arg`) that possibly might be getting set erroneously by some rogue package. Though this probably isn't very likely. I'm much more inclined to blame accidental key presses as you suggest (see [Ockham's Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor)).